# Sum rows of two tables

Tags: sql, sum

I have a Database with two tables:

```
subscriber_mm
uid_local   | uid_foreign   | uid_partner   
7           |2              |0      
7           |4              |0      
2           |1              |0  
2           |2              |0  
5           |1              |0      
5           |3              |0

partner_mm
uid_local   | uid_foreign   | uid_partner 
7           |1              |1
```

My goal is to count the total number of rows by uid_local from both tables
example:

```
count both tables by uid_local = 7
```

result: 3

example:

```
count both tables by uid_local = 2
```

result: 2

This is my solution (not the best) without the WHERE statement

```
SELECT sum(
ROWS ) AS total_rows
FROM (
SELECT count( * ) AS ROWS
FROM partner_mm
UNION ALL
SELECT count( * ) AS ROWS
FROM subscriber_mm
) AS u
```

how can i implement the WHERE statement?

Comment: - PHP-Version: 4.4.9  - Server Version: 5.5.28 - ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here pass a value instead of 2 for your query :

```
select sum(total_count ) as total_count  from 
(select count(*) as total_count from subscriber_mm s where s.uid_local=2
union all 
select count(*) as total_count from partner_mm m where m.uid_local=2) as a
```

or

```
 select a.uid_local,sum(total_count ) as total_count  from 
    (select s.uid_local as uid_local, count(*) as total_count from subscriber_mm s group by s.uid_local
    union all 
    select m.uid_local as uid_local, count(*) as total_count from partner_mm m group by m.uid_local) as a  
group by a.uid_local
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of doing SUM since you need only to count the total number of rows returned from both tables for particular `uid_local`. The total rows can be obtained by using `UNION ALL` operator which clubs the resultset returned from both the tables **WITHOUT** removing the repeated records

```
Select count(*) as Result From

(

Select * from subscriber_mm
where uid_local=7
union all
Select * from subscriber_mm
where uid_local=7

)as tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it

```
    select  uid_local,uid_foreign,uid_partner from subscriber_mm
union
select uid_local,uid_foreign,uid_partner from partner_mm
```

You can use Union For sum two table rows